# How to set the REMOTE_USER variable from Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, authentication, mod-rewrite

I have created a specific file in conf format in Apache. The goal is to set the REMOTE_USER into the conf file. I have tried to use RequestHeader tag, but it doesn't work.
Anybody have any idea to deblock my issue please.

```
<IfModule !mod_headers.c>
   LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
</IfModule>

<LocationMatch ^/+Windchill/+authBadge(;.*)?>
  Require all granted
  RewriteEngine On
  RequestHeader set X-Remote-User "MY_USER"
</LocationMatch>
```

I use the Apache version 2.4.

Comment: Welcome at stack**overflow**. Funny or not, [Expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) is to *not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks and other chit chat* (in posts…).

Answer (score -1):

instead use the following methods:

```
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}
```

there is also a solution with mod_ssl

```
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried, but nothing change. I will try to read the documentation in details I think.

Comment: (Are you confident someone tagging *mod-rewrite* will successfully put *mod_ssl* to work?)

Comment: The first variant "RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}" is wrong, as the part after "expr" is interpeted as a condition on when to set the header, rather than the replacement string. See also: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader